# How to list all the UTF-8 characters used in a text file that are not part of the ISO 8859-1 charset with PHP?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a big (900+ MB) SQL (text) file saved in UTF-8. The content of the file is valid and is only UTF-8 (nothing double-encoded or in the wrong charset).

I want to parse this file to find all the UTF-8 characters used in this file that are not part of the ISO 8859-1 charset. As you know a-zA-Z in ISO 8859-1 are the same binary in UTF-8 so I don't want to list them.

It's because I found out that there is some `C2 A0` characters (UTF-8 non-breaking spaces) used. I normalized them to regular spaces because 2 different entries had the same text but were different (space and non-breaking space look the same to the user but are different for the database). Now I'm wondering if there are similar problems with other characters (like commas or quotes)?

I want to parse this file to list all the UTF-8 characters that are not present in ISO 8859-1 (Latin1). That way I will only list "special" UTF-8 characters that might be problematic and I will normalize them manually prior the insertion in the new database.

Here is what I would like:

```
$utf8CharList = array();
$handle = fopen('somefile.sql', 'r');
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $str = fread($handle, $charLenght); /*What would be the correct length? 1 or 2 or variable?*/
  if (charIsOnlyInUTF8($str)) { /*Since "a" is binary the same in UTF-8 and ISO 8859-1 I don't want to list it*/
      if (!in_array($str, $utf8CharList)) {
          $utf8CharList[] = $str;
      }
  }
}
fclose($handle);
print_r($utf8CharList);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far that's not working? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @Wooble I know I'm not a new user there... I don't know how to check if a character read is in UTF-8 or not.

Comment: You said the entire file is in correct UTF-8. So, by definition, yes. All of the characters are in UTF-8.

Comment: @Wooble You know that an "a" in UTF-8 is the same (binary speaking) than in ISO 8859-1?

Comment: @AlexV You know that he is right based on elementary logic? And you should read about how characters in UTF8 are encoded so you will get some light (hint -> bits)

Comment: Characters/codepoints in UTF-8 encoding can be 1 to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem to me that you'd want to find any *non-ASCII* characters, as even "Latin-1 characters" may come in different flavors (composed vs. decomposed for instance; not sure if you care about that, but may be important). Since all ASCII characters are a single byte and all other characters are two or more in UTF-8, this is a pretty trivial operation.

```
for ($i = 0, $length = mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8'); $i < $length; $i++) {
    $char = mb_substr($string, $i, 1, 'UTF-8');
    if (strlen($char) > 1) {
        echo 'Found a non-ASCII character: ', $char, ' (', bin2hex($char), ')', PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really not a complicated question.

You basically want an Ord() for utf8.  Ascii characters in utf8 have an ordinal value < 127.

However, utf-8 characters > Ord() 255 will be in 2-4 character sequences, so, if reading a utf-8 file byte by byte, you have to know whether or not you are in a multibyte utf-8 character sequence. There are a number of implementations of routines you can use in the comments of the http://php.net/ord page.

Rather than copy them here, I would urge you to determine which of them appeals to you to solve your problem.

Comment: ordutf8 in ord PHP doc page works but is painfully slow. deceze's solution is blazing fast in comparison.